# Couldn't send the image to the web server database for android

Tags: android, http, inputstream, outputstream, dataoutputstream

I was instructed to send a report in this format

```
Name=tan ah kow 

Email=myemail@google.com

Contact=81234567

Block=123

Street=Tampines Central

Description=Dirty water puddle

uploadedfile=a5fa23423-4907098 (BASE64-ENCODED STRING)

index=1
```

Set the HTTP Header "Content-Type" as "multipart/form-data; boundary=BOUNDARY_STRING"

Form the HTTP Body Message according to the HTTP POST Specifications for multipart/form-data
FORMAT IS

```
--BOUNDARY_STRING\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Name\"\r\n\r\n
tan ah kow\r\n
--BOUNDARY_STRING\r\n
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Email\"\r\n\r\n
myemail@google.com\r\n
...
...
...
--BOUNDARY_STRING\r\n
Content-Dispostion: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"android.png\"\r\n
Content-Type: MIME-TYPE\r\n
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary\r\n\r\n
a5fa23423-4907098a5fa23423-4907098a5fa23423-4907098a5fa23423-4907098a5fa23423-4907098a5fa23423-4907098a5fa23423-4907098\r\n
--BOUNDARY_STRING--
```

If there is only 1 photo uploaded, just send one http post, and set index=1.
If there are 2 photos, send two http post of the same data (name, email, contact, etc) except for uploadedfile, which should be the data for the second photo, and set index=2.
If there are 3 photos, send three http post of the same data (name, email, etc) except for uploadedfile, which should be the data of the third photo, and set index=3.

The server will handle the linking of the photos to the correct report.

Following code for send images to server but didn't work. I hope anyone can help me.

```
String urlFEEDBACK = "http://zendragon.sg/tampinestc/report.php";

     private class NewFeedbackReportAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, String>, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute () {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(HashMap<String, String>... arrHashMapParameters) {
            HashMap<String, String> hashmapInput = arrHashMapParameters[0];
            String strPost = "source=android";
            Iterator<Entry<String, String>> it = hashmapInput.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, String> pairs = (Map.Entry<String, String>)it.next();
                strPost += "&"+(pairs.getKey() + "=" + pairs.getValue());
                it.remove();
            }
            String strFileData = convertPhotoToString(bmp);
            String result = null;
            try {
                result = multipartRequest(urlFEEDBACK, strPost, strFileData);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            showResults();
        }

    }
```

***This code is to convert bitmap to BASE64-ENCODED String***

```
protected String convertPhotoToString(Bitmap theBitMap) {
    if(theBitMap == null) {
        return null;
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    theBitMap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 60, bos); 
    byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();

    return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(array, android.util.Base64.NO_WRAP);
}
```

***This is the codes that send to the server.***

```
 public String multipartRequest(String urlFEEDBACK2, String strPost, String strFileData) throws ParseException, IOException{
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String boundary = "BOUNDARY_STRING";
    String result = "";

    try {
        URL url = new URL(urlFEEDBACK2);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setUseCaches(false);

        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
                "Android Multipart HTTP Client 1.0");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);

        outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Name\"" 
                + lineEnd + lineEnd + strName + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Email\"" 
                + lineEnd + lineEnd + strEmail + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Contact\"" 
                + lineEnd + lineEnd + strPhoneNo + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Block\"" 
                + lineEnd + lineEnd + strBLK + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Street\"" 
                + lineEnd + lineEnd + strStreet + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Description\"" 
                + lineEnd + lineEnd + strDescription + lineEnd);

        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\"; filename=\"android.png\"" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/png" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary" + lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        if(bmp!=null) {
                       //EDITED
           outputStream.writeBytes(strFileData);
           //ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           //bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
           //baos.writeTo(outputStream);
           //baos.close();

        }

        outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens);

        inputStream = connection.getInputStream(); 
        result = this.convertStreamToString(inputStream);

        // Clean up
        inputStream.close();
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

        // Log see debug
        Log.d(getString(R.string.app_name), "Result: "+ result);
        checkResponse(result);
        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("MultipartRequest", "Multipart Form Upload Error");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "error";
    }
}
```

***EDITED: ***
I can't seem to see any problem with my codes to send/write the image to the web server. Hope anyone can point out what is my mistake here. I need to solve this asap as my boss keep on asking me. Hope anyone can help me out here. Any help will be appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Comment: also, there is `NameValuePair` and `URLEncodedUtils` that already does  the formating for the strPost.

Comment: @njzk2 the image is not send/write into the database which i don't know why. the person who handle the database said that the baos.writeTo(outputStream); giving the problem.

Comment: @njzk2 I have already edit a bit on how I was supposed to format it.how do I send the report using NameValuePair and URLEncodedUtils using the format above? And I manage to send the Name, email etc. Only image have a problem.

Comment: do you have some logs on the server ? there should be an error or something when trying to read the image

Comment: @njzk2 sorry I'm kinda new in android esp when comes with server. Urmm...I don't think I have the logs cos I didn't handle the server. What do you mean by trying to read the image? It is the image is not insert in bmp? Thank you very much.

Comment: just read a part of your question I hadn't so far. you are supposed to Base64-encode your image. you are not. in fact, you are explicitely transferring it in binary.

Comment: @njzk2 so I need to change this part:  if(bmp!=null) {
           ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
           baos.writeTo(outputStream);
           baos.close();
        } ?

Comment: i think so. you need to write in a base64 stream, which in turn writes into your request stream

Comment: @njzk2 i have already change the codes but I still can't write it on the web server. :/

Comment: you'll need the server log, i think.